# How to change value for list data structure firebase database android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to change **readStatus** value from 1 to 2 as per **memberId** as show in attachment. I am unable to change is directly using single Query. How to change it?

I tried with

```
 HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("readStatus", "2");

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Message")
            .child(idRoom)
            .child("ChatMessages")
            .child(messageId)
            .child("Status")
            .child("memberID")
            .updateChildren(result);
```

But it adding new child as memberId - that I got because of above query is not right. How can I achieve this query?

Comment: Why not change your datastructure to use the memberID as a key directly under status and 1 or 2 as the value?

Comment: @AndréKool I am using Model for above structure. with use of push() method I am getting this type of strucutre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to this, you are trying to update a value into a reference that does not have your readStatus key

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Message")
            .child(idRoom)
            .child("ChatMessages")
            .child(messageId)
            .child("status")
            .child("0")
            .updateChildren(result);
```

if you want each member to have a readStatus you should change your database to this

```
status
|_ "your_member_id"
       |_ readStatus: 1
```

instead of

```
status
|_ 0
   |_ memberId: "your_member_id"
   |_ readStatus: 2
```

Also you have some typos in your reference, for example `.child("memberID")` does not exist at your database, and `.child("Status")` is with uppercase and you have it there with lowercase `"status"`

if you change your database Structure as above you should update your value this way

```
 HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("readStatus", "2");

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Message")
            .child(idRoom)
            .child("ChatMessages")
            .child(messageId)
            .child("status")
            .child(memberId)
            .updateChildren(result);
```

also, there is no need to use a map to update that children, you can just use `setValue();` , it will overwrite the current resultStatus

```
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Message")
                .child(idRoom)
                .child("ChatMessages")
                .child(messageId)
                .child("status")
                .child(memberId)
                .child("readStatus")
                .setValue("2");
```

Comment: not working. It is removing list of status and updating new field as Uid with read status 2. It is not working as per my requirement

Comment: im suggesting to change your database, if you want to archieve it with your current database you cant update the read value of a certain memberID because the readStatus and member id are at the same place, read carefully my answer, feel free to ask any doubt . In the last part of my answer you can change mAuth..... with just 0 or 1 and it will work for your database, but if you do that your memberID inside 0 and 1 is obsolete since it will not identify which user reads that message

Comment: Is there any way to set database as you suggest with Model class?

Comment: yes, can you show me where are you doing the push to push those 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 childs inside status node ? and where are you creating memberid and status inside each one

Comment: https://ibb.co/jrkd48 - here is I am creating Model. and pushing like this :         FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(MESSAGE_OBJ)
                .child(roomId)
                .child(CHAT_MSG)
                .push().setValue(newMessage);

Comment: i want to know how you create inside status those values, i know is an arraylist that creates those 0 , 1 , 2 and so on, but how you get memberId , because .setValue(newMessage) sets the whole message, i just want to know the part of status, how you place the values inside that node

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174805/discussion-between-gaston-saillen-and-nik).